# Group and Average in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to group the records by movie id and then find the average of each movie

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!!!. Please provide code and samples of what you tried and the error you are facing for better help and resolution.

Answer (score 0):

```
--load in data with appropriate load method

A = GROUP data BY movie_id;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE group, AVG(data.Rating) as average_rating;
```

Assuming you want the average rating and not the average timestamp?